# How to make a string safe for an href attribute using PHP?

Tags: php, sanitization

Would encoding quotation marks and removing eventual `javascript:` prefixes be enough?

P.S. Safe enough to defeat XSS attacks that is.

Comment: Your question is way toooooo unspecific to make clear what the term "safe" in the title stands for. You might want to filter protocol URLs thought, but then you should ask for that. Context is okay, but keep your question to the part you want to learn about.

Comment: @hakre, safe enough to defeat XSS attacks that is.

Comment: well, then I'd like to make clear that removing the verbatim `javascript:` is not enough to prevent XSS in a href attribute. Instead I highly recommend you do some whitelisting here (that is far easier to implement and you don't need to be a super-pro to make this safe)

Comment: @hakre, would you mind elaborating on that in an answer?

Comment: If you understand a bit into which direction I pointed to, why not formulate the answer your own, then ping me and I take a look?

Comment: @hakre, how would the whitelisting approach work if I want to accept relative urls too?

Comment: Relative URLs are always relative to a base URL.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the php function to validate urls

```
$url = "http://google.com";
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
  echo "URL is valid";
}
else {
  echo "URL is invalid";
}
```

Comment: I'm not interested in validation. I'm rather interested in making  a string safe (sanitization) regardless of weather it is a valid URL or not.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding with [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) with the `ENT_QUOTES` flag will technically make the URL safe/sanitary for use from an HTML perspective, but it does not guarantee that it'll create a valid address.

```
$url = 'http://invalid"url';
$url = htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES); // Yields "http://invalid&quot;url"
```

Comment: Using `htmlspecialchars()` makes the URI safe for using it in an HTML attribute. It guarantees valid HTML, but it does not help anything in regards of security (=the OP wants to protect the users from being presented with malicious JavaScript links).